# Graphics artifacts after update. Radeon RX and Ubuntu 20

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, radeon, screen-corruption

Graphics artifacts started appearing in many web browsers following a recent update.  I run KDE through ubuntu 20.04 and am up-to-date as of 8-31-2020.  My graphics card is Radeon RX 580.  I have tried the non-proprietary drivers and the AMD supplied drivers, the problem shows up the same with either set of drivers.  The problem occurs with all browsers I have tried (Firefox, Brave, Chrome, and Chromium).  It seems to be related to layers.  The artifacts are blocks that appear in the lower left triangle of the screen and flicker whenever I type, move the mouse, and even flicker in time with the blinking cursor.  See two attached screen shots for samples.

[image: See image corruption in top left corner of window]

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem RX 5700 xt

Comment: Exact same problem with Radeon RX 590.  By the way, the problem is in the top left corner as your screenshots show (not in the lower left as in your description).

Answer (score 4):

Workaround available for Chromium browser mentioned on [Chromium bugs site](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1122224#c14).

Running `chrome` or `chromium` with `--use-gl=desktop` bypasses the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Disable hardware acceleration in Google Chrome by going to *3 dots menu* → *Settings* → *Advanced* → *Disable hardware acceleration*.

After that relaunch the browser.

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer specifying how to disable the hardware acceleration?

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same problem with a quadro p1000.  I'm starting to think that there was something bad in the 20.04 upgrade.

I ran `nvidia-settings`.  I'm not sure if there is a similar settings tool for Radeon. (maybe `radeon-settings`)

Then, I set the OpenGL Image settings to `Performance`, then `Save to X Configuration file` (which auto merges with `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`).  Did a reboot for the changes.

So far I haven't observed any issues in the past 3 days.

Comment: this topic is about Radeon, not Nvidia